# android alarmmanager broadcast reciever not being called

Tags: android, android-alarms, android-broadcast, android-pendingintent

hey guys was hoping you could help me out.

I am a novice anodroid developer using alarmManager for the first time, but the broadcast receiver dosent seem to be being called.

heres the code that creates the alarmManager

```
AlarmManager alarm=(AlarmManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent i=new Intent(this,AlarmReciever.class);
        PendingIntent p=PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 22, i,PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

        alarm.set(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP,1,p);
```

and the broadcast reciever class

```
Public class AlarmReciever extends BroadcastReceiver{

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context c, Intent i) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Toast toast1= Toast.makeText(c, "This text will be displayed \n on the toast", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        toast1.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL, 0, 0);
        toast1.show();

    }


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you add the following code in your manifest ?

```
<receiver
   android:name="AlarmReceiver"
   android:process=":remote" >
</receiver>
```

Comment: You won't need the ':remote', because it is not needed in a seperate process. Furthermore I would suggest to use the name '.AlarmReceiver' (note the dot) therefore the namespace of the receiver is the same as the package.